# Telegram bot not able to send message after reply keyboard

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am new to Telegram bot api and am trying to make a simple bot with an inline keyboard. My bot is working fine but is not able to send back messages after the final inline keyboard option selected. Here is my code:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler,MessageHandler,Filters,CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton,InlineKeyboardMarkup,KeyboardButton,ReplyKeyboardMarkup
def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Hi, I am Food Bot')
    update.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(),
                            reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def main_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=main_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def first_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=first_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())

def second_menu(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=second_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=second_menu_keyboard())
def main_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Breakfast', callback_data='op1')],
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Lunch or Dinner', callback_data='op2')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def first_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Omelette and 2 Bread slices with coffee',callback_data = 'b1')],
                     [InlineKeyboardButton('Aloo paratha with curd and tea',callback_data = 'b2')],
                     [InlineKeyboardButton('Masala dosa with sambar and chutney with coffee',callback_data = 'b3')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def second_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Paneer Makhni with 2 rotis and rice',callback_data = 'l1')],
                     [InlineKeyboardButton('Pasta in white sauce with 2 pieces of garlic bread',callback_data = 'l2')],
                     [InlineKeyboardButton('Biryani with raita',callback_data = 'l3')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
def main_menu_message():
  return 'What do you want to order?'

def first_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the food option:'

def second_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the food option:'
def breakfast1(bot,update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id,
                        text='Your order: Omelette and 2 Bread slices with coffee')
def breakfast2(bot,update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id,
                        text='Your order: Aloo paratha with curd and tea')
def breakfast3(bot,update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id,
                        text='Your order: Masala dosa with sambar and chutney with coffee')

def lunchdinner1(bot,update):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id,
                        text='Your order: Paneer Makhni with 2 rotis and rice')
def lunchdinner2(bot,update):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id,
                        text='Your order: Pasta in white sauce with 2 pieces of garlic bread')
def lunchdinner3(bot,update):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=update.message.message_id,
                        text='Biryani with raita')
def main():
    bot=telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='op1'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_menu, pattern='op2'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(breakfast1,
                                                        pattern='b1'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(breakfast2,
                                                        pattern='b2'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(breakfast3,
                                                        pattern='b3'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(lunchdinner1,
                                                        pattern='l1'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(lunchdinner2,
                                                        pattern='l2'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(lunchdinner3,
                                                        pattern='l3'))


    updater.start_polling()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On selecting one of the options of the main menu, next menu appears accordingly, but when the option is selected from the second menu, nothing happends even though I have added handler for the callback data of those option and the functions must send the message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, [read](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py) this code and use ConversationHandler instead of this. you just have to return user to a specific state and wait for a Command, Message, or Callback then get updates and after detecting user action do your job.

- when you initial an Updater you don't have to initial a Bot too. updater object pass both bot, update to your functions when got user input.

Comment: how do I use the error handler in the code along with the bot and update parameters? the code uses `use_context`, which passes `update` and `context`, but I need the `bot` parameter as well

Comment: i prefer using version 11.1.0 that don't need use_context, and also here update is update and context is instead of bot instance.

Comment: does the context parameter have the same methods as bot? the documentation showed different methods.I need the `bot.edit_message_text` which is not in `context`